# Does we have ways to open mail with `mailto:` method , then fill that mail with content body later?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, mailto

I got a case that is the body content mail is Japanese so when i put it in mailto , maybe they encode that content . So the url `mailto:...` over 2000 characters. So mail cannot open it.

So i thinking do we have some ways to open an mail then insert content later or another way to archive this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.

That would require the browser and the email client to provide an API that would allow the email content to be manipulated.

They don't.